# variable dataframe name - loop works by itself, but not inside of function

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have dataframes that follow name syntax of 'df#' and I would like to be able to loop through these dataframes in a function. In the code below, if function "testing" is removed, the loop works as expected. When I add the function, it gets stuck on the "test" variable with keyerror = "iris1".

```
import statistics
iris1 = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris2 = sns.load_dataset('iris')

def testing():
    rows = []
    for i in range(2):
        test=vars()['iris'+str(i+1)]
        rows.append([
            statistics.mean(test['sepal_length']),
            statistics.mean(test['sepal_width'])
        ])
testing()
```

The reason this will be valuable is because I am subsetting my dataframe df multiple times to create quick visualizations. So in Jupyter, I have one cell where I create visualizations off of df1,df2,df3. In the next cell, I overwrite df1,df2,df3 based on different subsetting rules. This is advantageous because I can quickly do this by calling a function each time, so the code stays quite uniform.

Comment: It isn't advantageous, because you're looking to make use of global lookups (which will be buggy here) and you're not returning anything from that function anyway. Your dfs should be in a dictionary that you pass to the function and iterate through

Answer (score 1):

No...

You should NEVER make a sentence like *I have dataframes that follow name syntax of 'df#'*

Then you have a `list` of dataframes, or a `dict` of dataframe, depending how you want to index them...

Here I would say a `list`

Then you can forget about vars(), trust me you don't need it... :)

EDIT :

And use list comprehensions, your code could hold in three lines :

```py
import statistics
list_iris = [sns.load_dataset('iris'), sns.load_dataset('iris')]
rows = [
    (statistics.mean(test['sepal_length']), statistics.mean(test['sepal_width'])) 
    for test in list_iris 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the datasets in a dictionary and pass that to the function.

```
import statistics
import seaborn as sns

datasets = {'iris1': sns.load_dataset('iris'), 'iris2': sns.load_dataset('iris')}

def testing(data):
    rows = []
    for i in range(1,3):
        test=data[f'iris{i}']
        rows.append([
            statistics.mean(test['sepal_length']),
            statistics.mean(test['sepal_width'])
        ])
        
testing(datasets)
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing as a list or dictionary allowed me to create the function. There is still a problem of the nubmer of dataframes in the list varies. It would be nice to be able to just input n argument specifying how many objects are in the list (I guess I could just add a bunch of if statements to define the list based off such an argument). **EDIT: Changing my code so that I don't use df# syntax, instead just putting it directly into a list

The problem I was experiencing is still perplexing. I can't for the life of me figure out why the "test" variable performs as expected outside of a function, but inside of a function it fails. I'm going to go the route of creating a list of dataframes, but am still curious to understand why it fails inside of the function.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @Icarwiz that it might not be the best way to go about it but you can make it work with.

```
test=eval('iris'+str(i+1))
```

Comment: It's a well-known problem that you shouldn't make "variable variables" but should instead use a `dict`. If they want to foot-gun themselves then they can just look in `globals()` but this is just terrible practice. Not only that, but see [eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). What you've suggested is bottom of the list of things to try in fixing the OP's issue, please don't recommend `eval`